# Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException:

Tags: java, массивы, сортировка

Не могу разобраться в чем ошибка.

Выдает:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: 7
at Main.sortArray(Main.java:39)
at Main.main(Main.java:17)
```

**КОД:**

```
public class Main {

    static Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in);

    public static  void  main (String[] args){

        int [] myArray = getArray(7);

        sortArray(myArray);



    }



    public static int[] getArray (int count){
        System.out.println("Enter " + count + " numbers");
        int [] array = new int[count];
      for(int i = 0; i < array.length; i++){
          array[i] = scanner.nextInt();
      }
      return array;

    }

    public static void sortArray(int [] array){

        for(int i = 0; i < array.length; i++){

            if(array[i] > array [i+1]){
                int b = array[i];
                array[i] = array[i+1];
                array[i+1] = b;

            }
        }
        System.out.println(Arrays.toString(array));
    }

}
```

Answer (score 2):

Логично. Ведь когда цикл в `sortArray` доходит до последнего элемента  и попадает на строку

```
if(array[i] > array [i+1])
```

то `i + 1` указывает на элемент за границей массива

...

а еще из-за `array.length` в цикле `for` итераций больше происходит, чем элементов в массиве

Answer (score 0):

все, разобрался)
  for(int i = 0; i < array.length - 1; i++)